# DataRow in C# over VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

NET code

```
Public Function dbStringValue(ByVal drw As DataRow, _
                                  ByVal sColumnName As String) As String
        If IsDBNull(drw.Item(sColumnName)) Then
            dbStringValue = ""
        Else
            dbStringValue = CType(drw.Item(sColumnName), String)
        End If
End Function
```

now this is part of a clean up code which interrogates a datarow for null values. A datarow is passed along with the column name. I have tried to con vert it to c# as follows

```
public static string dbStringValue(DataRow drw, string sColumnName)
{
    string functionReturnValue = "";
    if (drw(sColumnName) != System.DBNull.Value)
    {
        functionReturnValue = (string)drw(sColumnName);
    }
    return functionReturnValue;
}
```

however there is no Item property for the datarow and googling suggest having it as datarow("ColumnName"). Using this method I keep getting drw is a variable but used like a method error.

Can anybody help

Comment: One of the strange things of VB.Net, using `()` for array index. Just weird.

Comment: That is to be inline with VB syntax, for natural transition for VB developers

Answer (score 2):

```
datarow["ColumnName"]
```

is the correct usage, as you have to access the indexer , difference is the `C# syntax`

Comment: VB.net use a parenthesis while C# uses square brackets.

Comment: Yes because that's more in line with VB syntax, MS wanted natural transition for the VB developers

Answer (score 0):

as soon as I posted this question I noticed its

```
["ColumnName"]
```

rather than

```
("ColumnName")
```

I have changed this and now it seems to be fine.

Comment: This shall be a comment not answer, as you realized your own mistake